# Problemas al pasar valores de json

Tags: php, javascript, css, html5, css3

Tengo el siguiente código:

```js
$.post("php/llenar.php",{opcion: op}, function(data){
  $("#valor").html(data);
 });
 $("#valor").change(function(){
  $("#valor option:selected").each(function(){
   op = "valor";
   valor= $(this).val();
   $.post("php/llenar.php",{opcion: op, valor: valor}, function(data){
    $("#valor1").val(data.valor);
    //$("#cedula").val(data.cedula);
   }, "json");
  });
 });
```

```css
$valor = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['valor']);
  if(empty($valor)){
   $sql="SELECT codigovar, descripcion FROM valores";
   $result=mysqli_query($con, $sql);
   $html.="<option valur=''>Escoga una opción</option>";
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
   {
    $html.="<option value ='".$row['codigovar']."'>".$row['descripcion']."</option>";
   }
  }else{
   $sql  = "SELECT valor FROM valores WHERE codigovar = '$valor'";
   $result=mysqli_query($con, $sql);
   $row =  mysqli_fetch_array($result);
   echo json_encode(array("valor"=>$row['valor']));
  }
```

```html
<div id="contenedor">
 <h1 id="titulo-form"> Asignacion turno de trabajo</h2>
 <div id="form">
  <form>
   <select class="input-100" type = "text" id="tpveh" name="tpveh">
    <option value="0">Escoga un tipo de vehiculo</option>
    <option value="camioneta">Camioneta</option>
    <option value="carry">Carry</option>
    <option value="furgon">furgon</option>
    <option value="moto">Moto</option>
   </select>   
   <select class="input-100" type = "text" id="placa" name="placa">
   </select> 
   <input class="input-50" type="text" id="mod" name="cc" readonly="readonly">
   <input class="input-50" type="text" id="cap" name="nomape" readonly="readonly"> 
   <select class="input-50" type = "text" id="valor" name="valor">
   </select> 
   <input class="input-50" type="text" id="valor1" name="valor1"> 
   <input type = "button" value = " Registrar" class = "btn-enviar" id = "btn-enviar"/>
  </form>
 </div>
</div>
```

Al verificar si me esta jalando el valor de la base me percato que la consulta esta haciendo su trabajo como pueden ver en la siguiente imagen.

[image: Resultado de la consulta SQL]

Pero no esta asignando el valor al input, no se si estoy omitiendo algo.

Agradecería su ayuda.

Comment: Antes de esta línea: $("#valor1").val(data.valor); intenta poner un console.log(data) y mira ver en la consola que te trae.

Comment: `valor{"valor" : "70802"} ` NO ES UN Json valido, es un string

Comment: Y como hago para volverlo valido?

Comment: Dariel me aparece lo siguiente
valorArray{"precio":"1T FURGON"}

Comment: ¿Cómo es que te devuelve esto: `{"precio":"1T FURGON"}` si más arriba dices que te devuelve esto:  `{"valor" : "70802"}` ¿no será alguna confusión en cuanto a tu archivo `php/llenar.php`? Otra cosa importante es que el archivo PHP no debe sacar nada por pantalla, sólo el JSON que el cliente espera.

Comment: Estaba probando con otro campo de la tabla pero lo que quería mostrar es que la consulta si esta devolviendo bien el valor solicitado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gracias por la ayuda que me dieron, pero ya encontré el error, resulta y pasa que el código que subí del PHP es solo una parte, que pasaba cuando cerraba la conexión a la BD manda a imprimir la variable $html puse a imprimir esta variable en cada parte del código y quedo solucionado mi problema

```
<?php
include("conex.php");
$opcion = $_POST['opcion'];
//echo $opcion;
switch ($opcion){
    case "dpto":
        $dpto = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['dpto']);
        if (empty($dpto)){
            $sql  = "SELECT departamento.cod_depto, nombre FROM departamento ORDER BY nombre ASC";
            $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
            $html.="<option value = ''>Escoga un departamento</option>";
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
            {
                $html.="<option value ='".$row['cod_depto']."'>".$row['nombre']."</option>";
            }
        }else{
            $sql  = "SELECT cod_municipo, nombre FROM municipio WHERE cod_dpto = '$dpto' ORDER BY nombre ASC";
            $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
            $html.="<option value = ''>Escoga un municipio</option>";
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
            {
                $html.="<option value ='".$row['cod_municipio']."'>".$row['nombre']."</option>";
            }   
        }
        echo $html;
        break;
    case "placas":
        $tipo = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['tipovh']);
        $sql  = "SELECT placa FROM vehiculo WHERE tipovehiculo = '$tipo' ORDER BY placa ASC";
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
        $html.="<option value = ''>Escoga una placa</option>";
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $html.="<option value ='".$row['placa']."'>".$row['placa']."</option>";
        }
        echo $html;
        break;
    case "marca":
        $marca = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['marca']);
        if (empty($marca)){
            $sql  = "SELECT codigomarca, nombre FROM marcas ORDER BY nombre ASC";
            $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
            $html.="<option value = ''>Escoga una marca</option>";
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
            {
                $html.="<option value ='".$row['codigomarca']."'>".$row['nombre']."</option>";
            }
        }else{
            $sql  = "SELECT codigolinea, nombre FROM lineas WHERE codigomarca = '$marca' ORDER BY nombre ASC";
            $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
            $html.="<option value = ''>Escoga una linea</option>";
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
            {
                $html.="<option value ='".$row['codigolinea']."'>".$row['nombre']."</option>";
            }   
        }
        echo $html;
        break;
    case "valor":
    $codigo = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['cod']);
    //echo $codigo;
    if(empty($codigo)){
        $sql="SELECT codigovar, descripcion FROM valores";
        $result=mysqli_query($con, $sql);
        $html.="<option value=''>Escoga una opción</option>";
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $html.="<option value ='".$row['codigovar']."'>".$row['descripcion']."</option>";
        }
        echo $html;
    }else{
        $sql  = "SELECT valor FROM valores WHERE codigovar = '$codigo'";
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        echo json_encode(array("precio"=>$row['valor']));
    }
    break;
}
mysqli_free_result($result);
mysqli_close($con);?>
```